# git clone repos with xargs and jq to a subfolder with the name of .owner.login (part of .full_name)

Tags: curl, git, xargs, jq, github

## Goal

Clone repos into subdirectories named `.owner.login` (argument in Github's REST API) with `jq`, `git clone`, and `xargs`.

---

## Preface

I took a code somewhere that allowed me to clone repos with `jq`, `git clone`, and `xargs`. However, I was not able to set it up so that it would make a new parent directory  for each repos. (I am a Windows user but for what I am trying to achieve I was not able to query any other solution but this bash script. I do not have any knowledge of how GNU commands interact together and this is the most I can put together)

### Original code

```bsh
UserName=CHANGEME; \
curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$UserName/repos?per_page=1000" |\
    jq -r '.[].html_url' |\
    xargs -l git clone
```

### This is my modification:

```bsh
UserName=CHANGEME; \
curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$UserName/repos?per_page=1000" |\
    jq -r '.[] | .html_url, .full_name' |\
    xargs -l git clone
```

I got the same result as the original code. And this error log:
`fatal: repository 'repoauthor/reponame?' does not exist`

I don't know where the `\?` came from.

#### So I tried to debug it

by splitting the code into

```bsh
UserName=CHANGEME; \
curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$UserName/repos?per_page=1000" |\
    jq -r '.[] | .html_url, .full_name'
```

which returned this:

```
https://github.com/repo1name/repo1author
repo1name/repo1author
https://github.com/repo2name/repo2author
repo2name/repo2author
... etc
```

It returned `.html_url`, `.full_name` in 2 different lines instead of a single line.

I thought that it was the issue but then I tried to run `xargs` separately:

```
https://github.com/repoauthor/reponame |\
xargs -l git clone
```

It just make me go into the git help file.

### tl;dr

I need to integrate the strings generated by `jq` into `xargs`. However, `jq` generated the important string into two different lines, and MAYBE that's what's causing the bug but I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't give us a specific Github user for reproducing your specific issue, I have tested with other Github accounts that I know of myself.

There are two main issues with your attempts.

1. The individual arguments read by `xargs` should ideally be quoted.
2. `xargs` needs to call `git clone` with two separate arguments: the repository URL and the destination directory into which to clone it.

You may sort out the quoting of the arguments like this:

```bsh
curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$UserName/repos?per_page=1000" |
jq -r '.[] | [ .html_url, .full_name ] | @sh'
```

This extracts the wanted info from the response to the `curl` request into an array, and then uses the `@sh` operator to output a each such array as a line of shell-quoted words.

Strictly speaking, we could have used just `.[] | .html_url, .full_name | @sh` as the `jq` expression to get a stream of lines with single shell-quoted strings on them too, it doesn't matter for `xargs` the way we're going to use it.

Given this stream of words, we then call `git clone` via `xargs`:

```bsh
xargs -n 2 git clone
```

The `-n 2` means `xargs` will call the utility with two arguments from its input stream at a time.

Putting it together:

```bsh
curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$UserName/repos?per_page=1000" |
jq -r '.[] | [ .html_url, .full_name ] | @sh' |
xargs -n 2 git clone
```

Comment: I got this: `fatal: could not create work tree dir 'repoauthor/reponame?': Invalid argument`. The issue seems to stem from the fact that either jq or xargs generated an invalid character (a `\?` in this case).

Comment: @Xyd It would be so much easier if you cold mention what Github user you are working with. The error message mention a name with a question mark at the end, so I don't know why you're talking about `\?`.  Both `?` and `\?` are valid characters and strings in Unix directory names.  In short, I'm unable to reproduce your error, so I'm inclined to close your question as "unclear".

Comment: @Xyd I have no issues cloning into subdirectories with `?` and `\?` in their names, using the code in my answer.

Comment: It seems like `jq` generated a `'\r`. I tried using this to debug:`$ curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/Xyde/repos?per_page=1000" |\
> jq '.[] | .owner.login'|\
> xargs -t
echo 'Xyde'$'\r'
Xyde`

Comment: I think the problem stems from me using Windows and that it's an invalid character. Do you have a way to remove it?

Comment: @Xyd Insert `tr -d '\r'` in your pipeline, just after `curl`, or after `jq`, depending on what's generating the carriage-return character.